# update dom after jquery.load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I started to use Jquery `Load($('body').load('/some.html'))` function in my application.
My application contains many jquery codes that are initialized like `$('#id')`

I don't want to change all this codes to live or delegate functions, I just want to update or reload the dom of the page.

Easiest way to do this?

Comment: Update or reload it how? It's not overly clear what you're asking here.

Comment: Well, maybe you can remove Script tag for your custom javascript and include it after load is finished, this way it reexecute and you get it done.

Answer (score 4):

```
function myreadyFunction(){
   //all initialization stuff here
}

$(myreadyFunction); //for equivalent of $(document).ready(myreadyFunction);

$('body').load('/some.html',myreadyFunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

roasted, Thank you.
But it's not exactly I'm looking for.

Let's say I have "div" element with id "id123" in my /some.html file

There's some functions in my application that handles this element - $('#id123').text('text changed')

your code will not work in that case.

I'm asking about fully updating or reloading the dom of page